# UIPopoverController, how to set background for popover?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uipopovercontroller

UIPopoverController, how to set background for popover?

```
[[[self.popoverController contentViewController]  view] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
```

This doesn't work((
 Background in popover should be different than in tableView (root).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`UIPopoverController` is inherited from `NSObject` and it has no background property or own view for customizing view's background. So, in this case you can only manipulate the view of `contentViewController`.

And your code works fine for me. Background is blue in tableview now.

```
_popController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:settingsPopoverController];
[[[_popController contentViewController]  view] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
```